# How to import Reusable Blocks programatically?

Tags: block-editor

How to import Reusable Blocks programatically?

I would supply 20 or 30 .json files with Reusable Blocks and the theme admin would be able to use them in their posts or pages.

How could I import them programatically on theme activation?

Comment: Have you looked into how the import currently works? There'll probably be a function call somewhere which you can use in your theme activation

Comment: True, but I decided to create them as custom post types, as the import function might change at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution so far seems to be creating the Reusable Blocks as custom post types:

```php
wp_insert_post([
    'post_content' => '<!-- wp:shortcode -->
[slider]
<!-- /wp:shortcode -->',
    'post_title' => 'My Slider',
    'post_type' => 'wp_block',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'comment_status' => 'closed',
    'ping_status' => 'closed',
    'guid' => sprintf(
        '%s/wp_block/%s',
        site_url(),
        sanitize_title('my-slider')
    )
]);
```

This way, I can create a library of blocks, loop and import them all.

Probably, as @kero mentioned, the core JSON import works the same internally.

Comment: But how are you going to use those inside another post type, such as post or page?

Comment: I'll use it as a Reusable Block. As soon as I create one of those, it will appear in the new block section, last tab.